# Copying Forward list to a linked list not working

Tags: c++, linked-list

Hi for my c++ assignment i have to implement a bunch of functions and one of them requires me to copy the values from a forward list and store them in a linked list. My university uses a website called Edstem to run and mark the code. It goes through a bunch of tests in a file called tests.hpp

I wrote up my code for this specific function in another IDE and it works perfectly and i got it to print out all the nodes in the linked list.

here is my code that I did in repl.it to figure out how to apply it to my assignment

and this is what i get after running the test on the edstem website

this is from the tests.hpp

[image]

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include<forward_list>
using namespace std;


#include <iostream>

using namespace std;




class Node {
public:
    int data;
    Node* next = nullptr;

};



int main() {
  forward_list<int> flist1;
  flist1 = {1,2,3,4,5,6,5,3,7,3,5,2,6,3,6,34,3,65,6};
  
    Node * head = nullptr;
  Node * temp = head;
  
  
  


  
for (auto it = flist1.begin() ; it != flist1.end(); it++){
  if (head == nullptr){
    head = new Node();
    head->data = *it;
    temp = head;
  }else{
    if(temp != nullptr){
      temp->next = new Node();
      temp->next->data = *it;
      temp = temp->next;
    }
  }


  
  //temp->next = new Node();
 //temp->next->data = *it;
 // temp = temp->next;
}
  
temp = head;
  
while (temp != nullptr){
  cout << temp->data<< endl;
  temp = temp->next;
}
  
}
```

Here is the function that I have to implement

```
// Constructor from initializer list
// ***For you to implement

// This implements the functionality you see with, for example, 
// std::forward_list<int> my_list = {1,2,3}
// which creates a new linked list where the first node holds 1, second 2, and 
// third 3.
// The {1,2,3} here is of type std::initializer_list<int> and you 
// see this is the argument to this constructor (with data of type T
// rather than just int). 

// You can access the elements of a std::initializer_list via an iterator
// for example you can cycle through all the elements with
// for(auto it = input.begin(); it!= input.end(); ++it){Do something with *it} 
template <typename T>
Forward_list<T>::Forward_list(std::initializer_list<T> input)
{
    head_ = nullptr;
    Node * temp = head_;
for (auto it = input.begin(); it != input.end(); it++){
  if (head_ == nullptr){
    head_ = new Node(*it);
    temp = head_;
  }else{
    if(temp != nullptr){
      temp->next = new Node(*it);
      temp = temp->next;
    }
  }
  temp = head_;
  
    }



}

#endif
```

here is the class for the Linked List, the relevant parts

```
template <typename T>
class Forward_list
{
public:
    class Node
    {
    public:
        // A node will hold data of type T
        T data{};
        // next will point to the next node in the list
        // we initialise next to nullptr
        Node* next = nullptr;

        // Because we have already intialised the variables
        // the default constructor doesn't need to do anything
        Node(){}

        // To make life easier we also provide a constructor
        // that takes the T data to be copied into the data member variable 
        // There is an optional second argument which is
        // used to update the next pointer.  This defaults to nullptr 
        // if the constructor is called with just one argument.
        Node(T input_data, Node* next_node= nullptr)
        {
            data = input_data;
            next = next_node;
        }

        // Destructor
        ~Node(){}
    };

private:
    // private member variables for Forward_list
    // the trailing underscore is a stylistic choice to 
    // distinguish these as private member variables
    unsigned size_ = 0;
    Node* head_ = nullptr;
```

and the test function that is used

```
void test_initializer_list(void)
    {
        std::initializer_list<int> inputs = {5,23,1,105,-2,7,88,0};
        Forward_list<int> my_list {inputs};
        std::forward_list<int> real_list {inputs};
        for(unsigned i=8; i>0; --i)
        {
            assert(my_list.front() == real_list.front());
            assert(my_list.size() == i);
            real_list.pop_front();
            my_list.pop_front();
        }
    }
```

Comment: A quandary: If you don't know what's wrong, How can you know what's relevant?

Comment: When inserting nodes in the constructor, you know the state of the list: It's empty. Using a loop to fill the list is the right idea, but the head will only be null once, on the first iteration. You can take advantage of that. And since temp will always point to the last node you inserted, the only time it will be null is the very first time. You can take advantage of that, too. So if you test that there's at least one item in the initializer list and ad that firs node as the head an then start looping with the second node, about half of your code goes away.

Comment: I don't understand why you are using `std::forward_list` and not also using `std::list`.  The code looks like it is caught between using standard C++ linked-list classes and creating home-made linked list classes.

Comment: That's just what they made us do for the assignment. It's doing my head in. I know the code's correct but it just isnt working in their IDE

Comment: The issue to me is that the assignment is confusing.  You start off using `std::forward_list`, which is a singly-linked list.  Then you have `Forward_list` -- what is that supposed to be?  Is it supposed to be a home-made singly-linked list, basically mimicking `std::forward_list`?  If it is, why is `std::forward_list` in your program?  And why no other student asked this question to the teacher (or did they ask it)?  Seems obvious the confusing nature of this assignment.

Comment: Was the `Forward_list` class definition provided to you? If not, you should take [The Rule of Three](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) into account. If it was provided and you can't change it, the assigner would be an asshat if they copied a `Forward_list` in their test code. Regardless, know and observe the Rule of Three and its friends Five and Zero in your own code and you'll have a simpler life.

Comment: @user4581301 the class definition is clearly incomplete: it's missing the destructor. The one thing that can be criticized here is making `Node` public. Imho the exact internal representation should be an implementation detail and not be accessible to the user of the class...

Comment: @fabian The truth. While I was digging in deeper I noticed `flist1 = {1,2,3,4,5,6,5,3,7,3,5,2,6,3,6,34,3,65,6};` in the asker's test code and without the Rule of Three, that go boom, sooner or later.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the line

```
temp = head_;
```

at the end of the loop body. Otherwise you reset the node you're working with to the head node in every iteration regardless of whether you're at the first element or not.

Imho an alternative loop that doesn't have to consider 2 states would be preferable.

Additionally `size_` is never set in the constructor for some reason.

Here are both the version of your implementation with the bug mentioned fixed and a version implemented from scratch.

**Your version with fix**

```
template <typename T>
Forward_list<T>::Forward_list(std::initializer_list<T> input)
    : size_(input.size())
{
    head_ = nullptr;
    Node* temp = head_;
    for (auto it = input.begin(); it != input.end(); it++) {
        if (head_ == nullptr) {
            head_ = new Node(*it);
            temp = head_;
        }
        else {
            if (temp != nullptr) {
                temp->next = new Node(*it);
                temp = temp->next;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**My own version**

```
template <typename T>
Forward_list<T>::Forward_list(std::initializer_list<T> input)
    : size_(input.size()),
    head_(nullptr)
{
    auto it = input.begin();
    auto const end = input.end();

    if (it != end)
    {
        head_ = new Node(*it);
        ++it;
        for (auto temp = head_; it != end; ++it)
        {
            auto next = new Node(*it);
            temp->next = next;
            temp = next;
        }
    }
}
```